# elasticsearch query spend all time in create_weight

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two elasticsearch clusters with the same indexes and data on each cluster.
The same simple query takes milliseconds on cluster A but it takes more than 10 seconds on cluster B.

I used the _profileAPI and on the cluster B, I can see elasticsearch spend a huge time on create_weight operation.

```
  {
    "id" : "[dj3LJZL1RNuPEP7S0ZXFVQ][index_2018_12][3]",
    "searches" : [
      {
        "query" : [
          {
            "type" : "TermQuery",
            "description" : "n:8096344531",
            "time" : "441.2ms",
            "time_in_nanos" : 441271696,
            "breakdown" : {
              "score" : 0,
              "build_scorer_count" : 20,
              "match_count" : 0,
              "create_weight" : 441255457,
              "next_doc" : 0,
              "match" : 0,
              "create_weight_count" : 1,
              "next_doc_count" : 0,
              "score_count" : 0,
              "build_scorer" : 16218,
              "advance" : 0,
              "advance_count" : 0
            }
          }
        ],
        "rewrite_time" : 3967,
        "collector" : [
          {
            "name" : "CancellableCollector",
            "reason" : "search_cancelled",
            "time" : "79.4micros",
            "time_in_nanos" : 79420,
            "children" : [
              {
                "name" : "SimpleTopScoreDocCollector",
                "reason" : "search_top_hits",
                "time" : "42.1micros",
                "time_in_nanos" : 42166
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "aggregations" : [ ]
  },
  {
    "id" : "[dj3LJZL1RNuPEP7S0ZXFVQ][index_2018_12][4]",
    "searches" : [
      {
        "query" : [
          {
            "type" : "TermQuery",
            "description" : "n:8096344531",
            "time" : "296.7ms",
            "time_in_nanos" : 296795143,
            "breakdown" : {
              "score" : 0,
              "build_scorer_count" : 15,
              "match_count" : 0,
              "create_weight" : 296779276,
              "next_doc" : 0,
              "match" : 0,
              "create_weight_count" : 1,
              "next_doc_count" : 0,
              "score_count" : 0,
              "build_scorer" : 15851,
              "advance" : 0,
              "advance_count" : 0
            }
          }
        ],
        "rewrite_time" : 2947,
        "collector" : [
          {
            "name" : "CancellableCollector",
            "reason" : "search_cancelled",
            "time" : "54.7micros",
            "time_in_nanos" : 54776,
            "children" : [
              {
                "name" : "SimpleTopScoreDocCollector",
                "reason" : "search_top_hits",
                "time" : "18.6micros",
                "time_in_nanos" : 18642
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "aggregations" : [ ]
  },
  {
    "id" : "[dj3LJZL1RNuPEP7S0ZXFVQ][index_2019_01][3]",
    "searches" : [
      {
        "query" : [
          {
            "type" : "TermQuery",
            "description" : "n:8096344531",
            "time" : "173.2ms",
            "time_in_nanos" : 173260750,
            "breakdown" : {
              "score" : 0,
              "build_scorer_count" : 17,
              "match_count" : 0,
              "create_weight" : 173247380,
              "next_doc" : 0,
              "match" : 0,
              "create_weight_count" : 1,
              "next_doc_count" : 0,
              "score_count" : 0,
              "build_scorer" : 13352,
              "advance" : 0,
              "advance_count" : 0
            }
          }
        ],
        "rewrite_time" : 4606,
        "collector" : [
          {
            "name" : "CancellableCollector",
            "reason" : "search_cancelled",
            "time" : "47.5micros",
            "time_in_nanos" : 47584,
            "children" : [
              {
                "name" : "SimpleTopScoreDocCollector",
                "reason" : "search_top_hits",
                "time" : "15.8micros",
                "time_in_nanos" : 15809
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "aggregations" : [ ]
  },
  ...
```

On cluster B the TermQuery takes between 100ms and 500ms on each shard whereas it takes only a few microseconds on cluster A

What can I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

I solved my own problem, so I post it here !

In fact cluster B indexes were created by a snapshot restore of indexes of cluster A (that's why I add exactly the same data in each cluster). I think that's why the indexes where segmented.

To solve the slowness issue I had to do a forcemerge on each index:

```
POST /index_*/_forcemerge?max_num_segments=1
```

Comment: Happened to me as well after reindex from a remote cluster. Thanks for the solution.